# Sub-subReport execution returns "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, subreport

Here's my problem: I have a JasperReport (**mainReport**) with one subreport (**subReport**) which, at the same time, have one subreport (**subSubReport**). My problem comes when I try to execute it from my web app. Those reports are extracted from an Oracle database, thus I'm passing an InputStream as "path" for them.

Since I've been testing "paths" as InputStream (obtained from the same database) I know it works when I have a simple **mainReport**->**subReport** hierachy... that's why I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the way I'm passing the parameters to the **subSubReport**.

Since now if I wanted to pass some parameter (as the path) to the **subReport** it has to be defined in the **mainReport** (also passed to the **mainReport** as a parameter) and it had to be passed as a parameter from the **mainReport** to the **subReport**. For that reason, I'm pasing all the parameters, even those needed for the **subSubReports** to the **mainReport** (and I'm guessing that's not the correct way since I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded when executing`).

I'm following the next format to define where each one of my parameters has to go:

- **SUBREPORT_DIR**  for those reports that are stored in a local folder.
- **SUBREPORTxLEVELy**  for those reports that are in the database.

*Where:*

**x** defines the number of the **subReport** according to its position (the band where it is) in the **mainReport**

**y** defines the level where the parameter is necessary (in this case **subReport** is in level 1 while **subSubReport** is in level 2)

For example:

Having such a hierarchy I'm coding it the following way:

*Problematic hierarchy*

**mainReport**

------------> **subReport**

-------------------------> **subSubReport**

Note that I defined **SUBREPORT_DIR** and **SUBREPORTxLEVELy** because the report can either be found in a local folder or at the database and in my jasper design I have this expression for the subreports `IF($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}==null,$P{SUBREPORTxLEVELy},$P{SUBREPORT_DIR})` .

Here is the code used in each report and the java code to generate the report.

**mainReport**

```
<subreport>
        <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="18ff5513-835d-4910-b39c-6d41252b4679"/>
<subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT1LEVEL1">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT1LEVEL2">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[IF($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}==null,$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL1},$P{SUBREPORT_DIR})]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

**subReport**

```
<subreport>

<reportElement x="50" y="10" width="457" height="40" uuid="4528914e-bb9a-4300-8173-14be2ff2db85"/>

<subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">

        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>

</subreportParameter>

<subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">

<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>

</subreportParameter>

<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">

         <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>

        </subreportParameter>

<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT1LEVEL2">

<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>

</subreportParameter>

<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>

<subreportExpression><![CDATA[IF($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}==null,$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL2},$P{SUBREPORT_DIR})]]></subreportExpression>

</subreport>
```

**java code**

`parameters.put("SUBREPORT1LEVEL1", inputStream1);` (For **subReport**)    `parameters.put("SUBREPORT1LEVEL2", inputStream2);` (For **subSubReport**)

Didn't find necessary to post the rest of the Java code 'cause I know it works how it's supposed to.

The three reports compile perfectly in the designer (each one separated) generating the .jasper file correctly.

So, my questions being said:

- What am I doing wrong?
- How am I supposed to pass the parameters to
  define the report path for a subSubReport?
- Does the parameter need to
  be passed to the mainReport as I do when I have a subReport?

In conclusions, I want to be able to asign the correct InputStream to each **subReport**/**subSubReport**, which one is the better (and known) way to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Question asked at: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1042586/sub-subreport-execution-returns-javalangoutofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit

Comment: How are the input streams declared and initialized?

Comment: Hard to understand if you are creating some strange recursion, but “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded” can also be caused by to much data loaded, check the jasper report [virtualizers](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/virtualizers-jasperreports).

Comment: Thank you @PetterFriberg, I'll give it a look and see what I can take!