# How to pass parameters to sub subreports from java code JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I'm having serious problems trying to figure out how to pass parameters to sub-subreports in jasperreports from java code.

The hierarchy I'm talking about looks like the following:

**mainReport**

--------------> **subReport**

---------------------------> **subSubReport**

So far, I tried to pass the parameters needed in the **subSubReport** to the **mainReport** and from there pass it to the **subReport** and from there to the **subSubReport** but this it's not working. In fact, I do get a pdf file with the contents of the **mainReport** and the **subReport** but the content of the **subSubReport** is not displaying. That's why I'm guessing my problem is that I shouldn't be passing the parameters (SUBREPORT_DIR more specifically) of the **subSubReport** to the **mainReport** but to the **subReport** and that's what I don't know how to achieve. Also, there is little (and incomplete) information on the web about it.

Can someone please help me?

**mainReport code**

```
<subreport>
                <reportElement key="" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="18ff5513-835d-4910-b39c-6d41252b4679"/>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT1LEVEL1">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL1}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

**subReport code**

```
<subreport>
                <reportElement x="50" y="10" width="457" height="40" uuid="4528914e-bb9a-4300-8173-14be2ff2db85"/>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT1LEVEL2">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT1LEVEL2}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are setting each report level with a parameter equalling itself, rather than passing it down.

What you need to do is pass the parameter from the level above for each level of sub-report e.g. if you have a parameter at the top level, you need to pass this to the sub-level via the associated sub-report parameter, and then pass this level's parameter to the sub-sub-report i.e. the next level down.

For instance, let's assume we want to pass a Boolean server check parameter from the top level to the bottom, with the parameters "IsOnserver", "IsOnserverL1" and "IsOnserverL2" for each respective report level. At the main report level we would have this:

```
<parameter name="IsOnServer" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[true]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

For the next level (the sub-report) we would do the following, to fill this with the main report parameter's value:

```
<parameter name="IsOnServerL1" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsOnServer}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

For your 3rd and final level parameter (the sub-sub-report) we would pass the sub-report parameter value:

```
<parameter name="IsOnServerL2" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsOnServerL1}]]</defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

This will result in the main report parameter being passed down the line correctly.

Comment: hi @philipobrien, your answer worked! Thank you very much! Now I just have to code this behavior on java xD

Comment: No problem, glad it helps.

Comment: Just one more question, what happens when my SUBREPORT_DIR is unique for each of the subreports? e.g.: when they are stored in a database and each register describes a report/subreport, here I couldn't say the defaultValueExpression is the same as the master report, right? How would you solve it in this case?

Comment: Without seeing the exact structure it's hard to say, but the same principle could be applied. Give me a few minutes and I'll post a separate answer showing a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the top level you would set and pass the initial parameters, like so:

```
--set all parameters at top level
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR0" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["level0Dir"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR1" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["level1Dir"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR2" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["level2Dir"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
--
-- pass parameters to level 1
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR1">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR2">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```

For level 1 you would set and pass the next set of parameters:

```
--set parameters at level 1
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR1" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR1}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR2" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR2}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>

--
-- pass parameter to level 2
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR2">
    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
```

for the final level you would set the remaining passed parameter:

```
-- set parameter at level 2
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR2" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR2}]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Comment: So, if I understood right, with you explanation I'll have to pass all the parameters I'll need in the subReports to the mainReport and it will be the one to be in charge of "passing" it to the subReports, right? I attempted to implement a recursive method trying to assign each report (subReport/subSubReport) the value of the specific parameter (e.g: SUBREPORT_DIR1 to level one, etc) but it didn't fully work. I'll try this one, assigning all the params to the mainReport and defining the xml like you showed. Thank you for the help, I think this answer will be very helpfull for a lot of people!

Comment: Yes, there may be a smarter way to do it, but this seems to be the most obvious and the quickest to implement.

Comment: I first tried this one you suggested, but from java code is kinda tricky to achieve it (at least for me that don't have much knowledge on how JR works) and there is not much information (almost none) on how to do it or which is the best way from java. I even posted a question here when I tried it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134673/sub-subreport-execution-returns-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-e) ...but not many use JR apparently. The question now would be, which is the best (fastest) way to do it? PS:That's should've been my question in the first place